# Is it possible to connect a tablet to the network without wifi via usb without otg adapters?

Tags: windows, networking, usb, ethernet, tablet

We must connect a tablet to the network without wifi access, using usb cables. As far as I know there are OTG adapters to do this, but I'm interested in doing this without those. (Not all of the tablets are working with them)

We don't have a specific tablet model, I'm interested in Windows and Android tablet solutions as well. We don't need ineternet on the tablets, but we must reach our servers on the network.

We are thinking to do this because our customers won't create wifi access to us. The tablets will be used as biometric signature sources (and for some other applications later as well). There will be a (Windows) PC with an administrator and the tablet. The customer will use the tablet, the administrator will use the PC.

1. Some time ago I heard about virtual ethernet connections via USB. I'm not sure but they were able to create ethernet network using the usb ports. I wasn't able to find such a solution this time, much more virtualized usb connections via ethernet.
2. In the old days I heard about connecting PCs to each other via usb cables to play games as they were connected to the same network.
3. That's all what I know at this moment. Unfortunately all that I was able to find isn't sufficient to me. Most of the articles are talking about "reverse tethering" between android tablets and PCs. Unfortunately we aren't allowed to root the tablets due losing warranty, and still we would need OTG adapters.
4. I'm not sure but USB 3. is maybe a solution although the host PCs probably won't have such a port.

Is it possible to create such a connection? If the answer is yes, how? Am I wrong in my listed points maybe? Do you have any more information?

I really appreciate any help in the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is simply a USB-ethernet adapter.
Unofortunately it totally depends on the tablet and the Operating System on the tablet whether or not a given ubs-ethernet adapter is compatible with it.
As far as I know you can't do it with Apple tablets. There are some solutions for Android based tablets and tablets running Windows Mobile.
For Windows based tablets (real Windows , X86 CPU) there are 100's of compatible devices. Actually you can use these on regular PC's too. They are the same.

I don't really see any other way to make this happen. Not unless you are willing to develop your own hardware and software for this.

There is a sort of in-between solution (if your customer is ok with it):
Connect your own wireless access-point/router to the customer network and have your tablet connect to that by Wifi.
Lock down the access-point so nothing else can connect to it. Effectively the access-point fills the same role as the usb-ethernet adapter and does nothing else.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How can I deciede that a tablet is a "(real Windows , X86 CPU)" one? 

Unfortnately they don't accept the access-point/router solution either. They reject any kind of wireless solutions.

Comment: If the tablet can run any arbitrary Windows software like a regular PC it is a full-fledged Windows PC in tablet form and it should be able to install the drivers for the usb-ethernet adapter like on a normal PC. Check the properties of "My Computer". It shows the Windows version used and what type of CPU is present. When in doubt you can always ask around here (post a photo of that screen so we get all the relevant information).

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just noticed today a USB female on my router.  I am only connected to ISP via ethernet.  I just plugged in a USB cable to my Samsung tablet USB, and VOILA!  A little popup window came along, asked for my passcode, which is on the side of the router.  Now I am connected.  Simple as that.  The router is kinda newish.